# Java - scanner doesn't pause when no input

Tags: java, servlets, network-programming, java.util.scanner

I am running a client and servlet under jetty locally. When I read the message in the client, I do:

```
in = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
StringBuffer messageBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while (in.hasNext()) {
   messageBuffer.append(in.next()).append(" ");
}
```

and I expect that when there is no data coming from the servlet, it should freeze at

```
while (in.hasNext())
```

instead, I just end up with empty messageBuffer, and i have to deal with it and call the method again and again until I get a message. Why is this happening? How can I make it stop at the while statement and wait until there is data coming in?

Here is how the url connection is started(once, in client constructor):

```
try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8182/stream");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioE) {
        ioE.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what `conn` is talking to. Is that a connection to the servlet?

Comment: Yes, conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); is HttpConnection

Comment: So why aren't you using an HTTP client library?

Answer (score 1):

from the Scanner doc:

> The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion
>   methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that
>   matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next
>   token. Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further
>   input. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or
>   not its associated next method will block.

it says that it might block, but it is not part of the api, it depends on the underline implementation according to what you scan.

anyway, you need to implement the wait yourself by something like:

```
while (!in.hasNext() && !stop){
   sleep();
}
```

Comment: Or not use a `Scanner` at all, which is probably the better suggestion here - an `InputStreamReader` wrapped by a `BufferedReader` is probably the more sane approach.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc states that `Scanner.hasNext()` and `Scanner.next()` *may* block. It really depends on the underlying `InputStream`. I personally wouldn't ever use a `Scanner` to read from a socket if that's what that is.

A more sane approach is probably to use an an `InputStreamReader` wrapped by a `BufferedReader`. Also worth mentioning is that you should be using `StringBuilder` rather than `StringBuffer` unless you need thread safety.

```
BufferedReader br = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String input = null;
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(input).append(" ");
}
```

Note this is using `readLine()` which may or may not suit your needs depending on what you're receiving. It also assumes the other end of the connection is going to close when it's done sending. You may want to use one of the `read()` methods instead and parse accordingly.

**Edit to add from comments below:** This is literally how blocking reads work in Java. Here's  a complete example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader br = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String input = null;
        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(input).append(" ");
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }
}
```

Output (cut off for brevity here, but it's the entire page):

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head> ...
```

Comment: If that "didn't work" then ... you don't actually have a connection (valid InputStream), which is the same reason your `Scanner` is bailing; it's hitting `EOF`.

Comment: By 'didn't work' I mean that even when there was no message, it went through the while loop and thought it had received empty message. Please read the question carefully. I want it to pause at the while loop until it finds input.

Comment: The above is literally a textbook example on how to perform a blocking read from an InputStream in Java; that's how it works. It will block if there is a valid stream (not at EOF) with no data currently available. If that's not what you're seeing you're doing something you're not showing us and what you're expecting to receive ... isn't what's being sent.

Comment: Gotcha. So, are you saying there can be a problem on the server side, with how it writes stuff? I.e. somehow the server is writing EOF at the end of every message when in fact it shouldn't? Is this what you are implying?

Comment: Dunno - I'm only going off the small snippit you provided. You might want to post a little more code showing how you're starting up the HttpURLConnection and getting to the code already posted.

Comment: I did. Please see original post.

Answer (score 0):

Edited :

try using for loop instead of while loop, where the range will be from 0 to (length -1). you will have to find length using while(in.hasNextLine()) and put length counter inside it .Dont forget to close the scanner after you are done with filling the messageBuffer (using .close()). just try it out. It should work.

Comment: Are you sure that you can know the length of a streamed content?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have always tried to avoid blocking and therefore have avoided using Scanner methods for hasNext().

Instead, I have used the InputStream. InputStream, which you have used in the code:

```
conn.getInputStream();
```

You can then use the InputStream method **available()** to see if any information has passed through.

So for your code, I would recommend:

```
InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
in = new Scanner(inStream);    
StringBuffer messageBuffer = new StringBuffer();    
while (in.available() <= 0)
{   
 try{
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
messageBuffer.append(in.next()).append(" ");
```